# Transformation (coordinates) - PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> > If I have $-\cos(x)u_x$ for $u\in C^2(\Omega), \Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ and 
> >     $$
> > \xi:=-x-\cos(x)+y, \eta:=x-\cos(x)+y
> > $$
> >     as transformation of the coordinates, what is then $-\cos(x)u_x$ after this transformation?

Do not know, how to solve this.

Comment: your Deutsch is showing!

Comment: What do you mean? :-)

Comment: The word "für" slipped in there :)

Comment: Oh, yes. I edited. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have 
$$ x = \frac 12(\eta - \xi) $$
and by the chain rule
\begin{align*}
  \def\pd#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}} \pd ux &= \pd u\xi\pd\xi x + \pd u\eta \pd\eta x\\
   &= (\sin x - 1)\pd u\xi + (1 + \sin x)\pd u\eta
\end{align*}
so 
$$ -u_x\cos x = -\Biggl(\left(\sin\frac {\eta-\xi}2 - 1\right)u_\xi + \left(1+\sin\frac {\eta -\xi}2\right)u_\eta\Biggr)\cos \frac{\eta-\xi}2 $$

---

*Addendum* (answer to question in comment about expressing $y$):
We have 
$$ \frac 12(\xi + \eta)= y - \cos x = y - \cos \frac{\eta - \xi}2 \iff y = \frac 12(\xi + \eta) + \cos \frac{\eta - \xi}2 $$

---

To calculate $u_{xx}$ we have $\def\x{\frac{\eta-\xi}2}$
\begin{align*}
 u_{x\xi} &= \Biggl(\left(\sin \x -1\right)u_\xi + \left(1+\sin\x\right)u_\eta\Biggr)_\xi\\
   &= -\cos\x \cdot u_\xi + \left(\sin \x - 1\right)u_{\xi\xi} - \cos\x\cdot u_{\eta} + \left(1 + \sin\x\right)u_{\eta\xi}\\
 u_{x\eta} &= \Biggl(\left(\sin \x -1\right)u_\xi + \left(1+\sin\x\right)u_\eta\Biggr)_\eta\\
   &= \cos\x \cdot u_\xi + \left(\sin \x - 1\right)u_{\xi\eta} + \cos\x\cdot u_{\eta} + \left(1 + \sin\x\right)u_{\eta\eta}\\
 u_{xx} &= u_{x\xi}\xi_x + u_{x\eta}\eta_x\\
    &= u_{x\xi}\left(\sin\x - 1\right) + u_{x\eta}\left(1 + \sin\x\right)
\end{align*}

Comment: and I'm pipped at the post! nice one.

Comment: Is there a way to express $y$ by $\xi$ and $\eta$, too? I don't see.

Comment: @math12 See above.

Comment: I thank you very (!) much!

Comment: One more question, sorry. How can I calculate $u_{xx}$ what means here: How can I calculate $((\sin\frac{\eta-\xi}{2}-1)u_{\xi}+(\sin\frac{\eta-\xi}{2}+1)u_{\eta})_x$?

Comment: Use the chain rule again: $(u_x)_x = u_{x\xi}\xi_x + u_{x\eta}\eta_x$

Comment: I have $u_{xx}=u_{x\xi}\xi_{x}+u_{\xi}\xi_{xx}+u_{x\eta}\eta_x+u_{\eta}\eta_{xx}$. What are $u_{x\xi}$ and $u_{x\eta}$? I mean: How to calculate this expressions?

Comment: @math12 See above.